# Adding advection to a diffusion model

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

I am attempting to add advection to my mathematica model of 2-D Diffusion.

I am trying to add a sine-flow vector field, which is `A*sin[x]` in the y direction and `A*sin[y]` in the x-direction. I attempted to decompose my original PDE using `Piecewise` and define them separately for even/odd t-timepoints, but I have having some difficulty with the formulation.

Attempted solution:

```
ClearAll["Global'*"]

k = 0.9;
m = 0.1;
A = 1;

sol1 = 
  NDSolve[
    Piecewise[
      {{D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
          (k*D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + m*u[t, x, y]*(1 - u[t, x, y]) + (A*Sin[y])), 
        t = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, 
       {D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
          (k*D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + m*u[t, x, y]*(1 - u[t, x, y]) + (A*Sin[x])), 
        t = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9}}], 
    {u[0, x, y] == Exp[((-(x - 2.5)^2)) + ((-(y - 2.5)^2))], 
     u[t, 0, y] == 0, u[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, 5, y] == 0, 
     u[t, x, 5] == 0}, 
    u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]    

Manipulate[
  Plot3D[u[t, x, y] /. sol1, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x - position, y - position, probability}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 1}}], 
  {t, 0, 10}]
```

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The main thing I see wrong is that your `Piecewise` expression makes no sense at all. Neither syntactically nor semantically. Another, somewhat lesser, error is that is the the argument structure you give `NDSolve ` is incorrect.

Comment: I'm attempting to add some sort of vector field to my PDE in 2-D, so I tried adding a sin component in the x and y-direction. Would there be an easier way to do this without using Piecewise?